# Are my prayers invalid?

Tags: salat

I’m a Muslim. I have started praying again after several years, it’s a bit difficult to memorize how to pray correctly so I feel nervous while praying and scared that I might do something that is wrong or mispronounce words while reciting (I don’t speak Arabic but i try my best). I heard somewhere that one of the pillars of salah is feeling at ease. So does this invalidate my prayers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact your trying and Allah SWT knows your intentions and if your intentions are pure in making salah right I assume your salah will be accepted but do learn how to pronounce and pray by watching videos or reading Arabic